# Displaying Arabic strings in Arcgis in Android (or installing

Tags: android, arabic, arcgis

I have been spending the last few hours trying to figure out why my Arabic strings are not appearing on the ArcGis map.

The rest of the app is happily displaying Arabic (included the map "callout"). I thought it might have something to do with:

TextSymbol textSymbol = new TextSymbol(22, name, Color.BLACK);

Where name is something like:

name: المدينة المنورة

Finally, I found a single line in the sparse ArcGis Android documentation:

"The language used by the app is determined by your device's language setting."

I have been setting the localization in the app explicitly with:

```
private void setArabic() {
    Resources res = getResources();
    // Change locale settings in the app.
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();

    conf.locale = new Locale("ar");
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
}
```

The ArcGis documentation seems to suggest that the app localization is ignored and Arabic needs to be set on the phone settings.

If this is true, I need to determine the standard way to do this and the user's of the app will need to do the same.

The Play Store has hundreds of localization apps that say they will add Arabic but is there a way to do this using Google code rather than untrusted 3rd parties?

Sincerely, FeiCui

Comment: Are they just not appearing, appearing as nothing, or appearing as gibberish?

Comment: They just don't appear. I found one comment in the sparse ArcGis documentation that says that it uses the language setting on the Android device. I was hoping there was some hook in the ArcGis toolkit that would allow forcing to Arabic.